# Plsql oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am using this loop in my procedure and taking the email ids in i but when i am trying to run i am getting no data found error, so i want to check the values storing in i

code used:

```
  for i in ( select EMAIL
              into l_user_mail 
              from employee A CONNECT BY PRIOR lower(EMAIL) = lower(MANAGER_EMAIL) 
                                START WITH lower(GUID) in  (select replace(lower(group_name),'_org_slack') 
                                                              from dynamic_group where id = '81')
           ) loop

    l_user_mail:=l_user_mail || i.EMAIL;
  end loop;
```

how to check the return value of i in sql command prompt.

i want to see the values getting in i

Comment: Remove the `into l_user_mail`, that's a first. Then after the loop finishes, you can just dbms_output the value of l_user_mail. Or, instead, you can concatenate the EMAIL column, using listagg built-in function, as `select listagg(email, '') from ...` - no pl/sql, no loops (no explicit loops that is) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to see the values getting in i

Your `FOR LOOP` syntax is not correct. `INTO` clause should not be used in `For Loop`. See below how you can do that.

```
 FOR I IN
          (SELECT     EMAIL
                 FROM EMPLOYEE A
           CONNECT BY PRIOR LOWER (EMAIL) = LOWER (MANAGER_EMAIL)
           START WITH LOWER (GUID) IN (
                             SELECT REPLACE (LOWER (GROUP_NAME), '_org_slack')
                               FROM DYNAMIC_GROUP
                              WHERE ID = '81') )
     LOOP
          -- l_user_mail:=:P60_IDP_GROUPS;
          L_USER_MAIL := L_USER_MAIL || I.EMAIL;
          -- To display value of I 
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (I.EMAIL);
     END LOOP;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2       L_USER_MAIL                   VARCHAR2 (10);
  3  BEGIN
  4       FOR I IN (SELECT     LEVEL
  5                       FROM DUAL
  6                 CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
  7       LOOP
  8            -- l_user_mail:=:P60_IDP_GROUPS;
  9            L_USER_MAIL := L_USER_MAIL || I.level;
 10            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (I.level);
 11       END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response, i have the code as you suggested still i am getting no data found "Error while Sending a Bot Message ORA-01403: no data found" is there is any possible to check the values storing in I

Comment: @Abinnaya Can you check if you query actually returning any rows. Run query standalone and check if it actually fetch any records.

Comment: Personally I've never seen "Error while Sending a Bot Message " come from a query in the database. Where does that come from?

Comment: @Abinnaya See the DEMO. It shows the output while using the for loop. Not sure what and how you trying to execute.